# Colour Has Too Much White Around Edges When Rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm super new to Blender, and am going through Blender Guru's Donut Tutorial for v 3.0.

At the rendering phase, when I use the cycles engine there seems to be too much white/blueish colour on the icing drippings, as shown in the pic below.

Any ideas about how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to decrease the Subsurface value of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: I tried turning it down and it seems to have helped. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the *Subsurface* value of the *Principled BSDF*. If you want to keep a bit of subsurface effect, you can change its color with the *Subsurface Radius* values (in RGB):

[image]